# Control scheme to regulate Vin using a Buck regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, shunt, differential-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

I am trying to create a control scheme that allows a buck regulator to regulate its input voltage instead of its output voltage. I'm trying to make an efficient shunting regulator. My current approach is

1. Use input voltage and link it to the adjust pin so the regulator can control it.
2. Take input voltage and first invert it so when Vin increases a falling voltage is seen on ADJ pin and the regulator passes more current thus bringing Vin down (and vise versa)
3. Compensate for a negative inverted Vin signal coming from the op-amp by adding a voltage to it giving ADJ an positive and correctly correlated response to Vin.

So far this isn't working. Some help on how to make a functional switch mode shunt regulator would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: LT3062 isn't a buck regulator

Comment: What is the specification of the power source you are trying to regulate and what impedance does it present?

Comment: Its a linear regulator I'm using it as a simple model for proof of concept of the control system.  The power source is a permanent magnet 3 phase generator that has been rectified to DC. Since it will generate various current at different RPM I'm trying to regulate the output voltage by shunting the excess current back to GND. I just need a functional control loop.